# Writing files with std on iOS

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, file, stl

i added a save.txt to my iPhone resource in xCode, with a same text "..."

i write some strings to the file, and than read it, but when i read it, i only get the old content.. so there is nothing new written into it

```
NSString* resources = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] resourcePath ] ;    

std::string respath( [ resources UTF8String ] ) ;

std::string fpath = respath + "/" + "save.txt" ;


std::ofstream file;

file.open(fpath.c_str(), std::ios::out );


file << "some text\n";

file.close();


std::ifstream rf;

rf.open(fpath.c_str(), std::ios::in );

char str[255];
while(rf) {
    rf.getline(str, 255);  

    if(rf) printf("%s", str);

}
```

Comment: Why use C++ when this is at least ten million times easier with Objective-C?

Comment: Do you really have to do it with std? In my opinion it's easier to use the NSString class to do this. :-D

Comment: Unless you have one of those "magical" iPhones that never fails and never runs out of space, you should check for errors.

Comment: because maybe it is cross platform

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot write or modify files inside the application bundle, that file.open() call is surely failing but you aren't checking for errors. Instead, you should write to the Documents folder for your app.

Per your code sample, that would be:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                       NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];

std::string respath( [ documentsPath UTF8String ] ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You never check for errors when writing. In fact, you are not writing to that file and error code, if checked, could have told you much more about what is wrong than my answer.